# log4j - Rolling File Appender not rolling based on Max File size

Tags: apache, logging, log4j, properties-file, rollingfileappender

Below is the code i used to generate the log files using log4j and then roll it based on size. Files are getting generated, however the files are not rolling over based on Max File size. I heard in one post that we have to use apache-log4j-extras and am using apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17. I tried to roll over once 50KB has been reached, but its not rolling over. Can someone please let me know what could have gone wrong?

Am using log4j-1.2.17 and apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17 version of jar.

```
log4j.appender.Flows=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Flows.File=E:/Logs/Flows.log
log4j.appender.Flows.MaxFileSize=50KB
log4j.appender.Flows.MaxBackupIndex=2
log4j.appender.Flows.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Flows.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p - %c %x %m%n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [Apache Extras™ for Apache log4j™](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/), you may want to use [`org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html):

```
log4j.appender.Flows=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender  
log4j.appender.Flows.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy  
log4j.appender.Flows.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=2  
log4j.appender.Flows.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy  
log4j.appender.Flows.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=51200  
log4j.appender.Flows.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=E:/Logs/Flows-%i.log  
log4j.appender.Flows.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=E:/Logs/Flows.log
log4j.appender.Flows.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.Flows.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p - %c %x %m%n
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is "rollingPolicy.maxIndex=2" same as "MaxBackupIndex"?

Comment: Not exactly the same. See more [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/FixedWindowRollingPolicy.html).

Comment: I used your code but even then its not rolling over as expected. The file size has increased beyond 100kb, still its not rolling over.

Comment: The size is in bytes without posfixe.

Comment: Does permissions play an important role in rolling over the files? My Files are created and its working in my local environments but the same script - properties file is not working (not rolling over) in another environment?

Comment: Humm... Nope. If you get the first file, everything is OK.

Comment: Thanks. Last question. my local is in Windows 8 and it works like a charm.. Same code is not working in my client machine which is windows server 2012 R2.. will difference in OS create an issue here?

Comment: this creates a bunch of empty files for me :/

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be caused by having the log4j*.jar in multiple levels of the class loader.
E.g. once provided by Tomcat and a second time provided by a web app directly. Removing log4j from our WAR in a Tomcat installation solved the problem for us.

Doing so, we could avoid the use of log4j extras.